# Issue building Confluent IO schema-registry source

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Building the [confluent schema-registry](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry) source has dependencies [rest-utils](https://github.com/confluentinc/rest-utils) & [common](https://github.com/confluentinc/common). rest-utils builds fine. Common needs [Kafka](https://github.com/apache/kafka) to be built (with Gradle) & Kafka builds fine.

Building [common](https://github.com/confluentinc/common) then gives the error:

> Failed to execute goal on project common-logging: Could not resolve dependencies for project io.confluent:common-logging:jar:5.4.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.kafka:connect-api:jar:5.4.0-ccs-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.kafka:connect-json:jar:5.4.0-ccs-SNAPSHOT

Note that the Kafka source includes: / connect/api & connect/json code though they have no separate build files.

Any tips on how to get this built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line seems to be the issue.

https://github.com/confluentinc/common/blob/master/pom.xml#L52

```
<kafka.version>5.4.0-ccs-SNAPSHOT</kafka.version>
```

So, you'd have to build the matching Kafka branch, which you can find here (note: this is Confluent's forked repo, not `apache/kafka`, which likely doesn't have a `5.4.0-ccs` version)

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka/blob/master/gradle.properties#L23

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! It highlighted for me that all the components I was building needed to be of the same version, in this case I was interested in Confluent 5.2.1, so I used this version of all of the above.

Confluent use Apache Kafka as well as many other components and does not fork Kafka, so you should remove that from your answer.

Comment: They fork it to build and test other components before committing back to upstream Apache project.